# Python 3. Помогите решить задачу

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет.
Наткнулся в учебнике "Как устроен Python. Мэтт Хариссон" 
на упражнение:

Создайте переменную name и присвойте ей свое имя. 
Создайте другую переменную — second_half, которая проверяет,
находится ли первая буква name во второй половине алфавита. 
Что необходимо для того, чтобы выполнить сравнение?

Логически я понимаю, какие команды, функции и операторы надо использовать,
но сформулировать в код не получается. 
Я новичок в программирование, и мне проще учиться на примерах.
Товарищи знатоки, покажите пожалуйста как реализовать данную задачу в рабочий код. Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```py
import string

name = 'Anton'
second_half = name[0].upper() in string.ascii_uppercase[len(string.ascii_uppercase)//2:]
```

1) Импортируем модуль string
2) В модуле string есть строка ascii_uppercase, вот что в ней хранится: `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`
3) Переменную second_half мы определяем с помощью логического выражения, в котором проверяется, находится ли первая буква имени во второй половине ascii_uppercase.

Обязательно приводим первую букву к верхнему регистру с помощью метода .upper(), потому что если вдруг буква будет в нижнем регистре, логическое выражение всегда будет выдавать False.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я думал использовать список (с алфавитом и перебирать в нём от среднего индекса до последнего) попросту просто не зная, что в модуле string есть такая строка. Но по скольку мало опыта и понимание только начинает приходить я не знаю как сформулировать пунк (3) из вашего ответа. Если подскажите буду очень благодарен. Это даст мне понимание.

Comment: @s3NhYpe Скажите подробнее, что именно не понятно, помогу разобраться